# Auto generating a String non-primary key value using jpa

Tags: jpa, mariadb

Kindly help me to find out a solution to my problem.
I have a property of type String in my entity which is not primary key.
This would act as system generated unique profile id for users in my project.
I want to auto generate this value like a random string of particular size.

Could you please help me to arrive at a solution.
 I have tried the @Generator and custom id generator class. but still null is getting inserted to the field in db.

I am using maria db.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hi you can use the hibernate events.

**@PostPersist**    Executed after the entity manager persist operation is actually executed or cascaded. This call is invoked after the database INSERT is executed.

Starting with Java 5, the **UUID class** provides a simple means for generating unique ids. The identifiers generated by UUID are actually universally unique identifiers.

Please follow the sample example.

```
public class TestModel {
    @Column("column_name")
    private String uid;

    //setter and getter for uid

@PrePersist
protected void onCreate() {
    // set the uid 
    setUid(java.util.UUID.randomUUID());

}
}
```

Please find the below link for more information on @PrePersist.
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.5/reference/en/html/listeners.html

Comment: Thanks Sudhakar.Implemented @PrePersist and the problem got solved.